# Haskell + output String as type String

Tags: string, haskell, io

I've written a basic recursive function:

```
bibliography_rec :: [(String, String, Int)] -> String
bibliography_rec [] = ""
bibliography_rec (x:xs) = (citeBook x) ++ "\n" ++ (bibliography_rec xs)
```

`citeBook` simply reformats the tuple into a String.

When run with this input:

```
ghci> bibliography_rec [("Herman Melville", "Moby Dick", 1851),("Georgy Poo", "Alex Janakos", 1666)]
```

It produces:

```
"Moby Dick (Herman Melville, 1851)\nAlex Janakos (Georgy Poo, 1666)\n"
```

I need line by line printing so I used this:

```
bibliography_rec (x:xs) = putStr ((citeBook x) ++ "\n" ++ (bibliography_rec xs))
```

My problem is my output NEEDS to be of type `String` NOT `IO ()`

I've been stuck on this for way too long so any help is great!

Comment: Values of type `String` *cannot* produce output. So your requirements ("I must produce output" and "the return type must be `String`") are in conflict.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're already there, you just need to `putStrLn` the string instead of `print`ing it (which is what ghci does by default).  `print` runs its argument through `show` first, so it will quote the escape characters like `"\n"`.

```
ghci> putStrLn $ bibliography_rec [...]
```

Comment: Only problem is I need to generate the String with only                          ghci> bibliography_rec [(...),(...)] or is there something im still missing. Also what does the $ do??

Comment: @ajanakos There's definitely something you're missing.  A `String` value is just a `String` value, in Haskell that means that it has no side effects and simply can't do things like print a value to the screen.  In GHCi when you evaluate a value, it performs an `IO` action behind the scenes so that you get to see a _representation_ of that value displayed, since otherwise the "interactive" part of GHCi wouldn't really be useful.  Note that code entered into GHCi is not the same as executing a `.hs` file.

Comment: @ajanakos The `$` operator has many, many discussions, clarifications, etc all over stackoverflow and the rest of the internet, I won't go into detail here, but suffice to say that it's a do-nothing operator with a specific order of operations so that you can drop parentheses frequently.  The above line of code could have been equivalently written as `putStrLn (bibliography_rec [...])` and it would have been identical in execution.  This comes in handy with things like `f $ g $ h 1` instead of `f (g (h 1)))`, where the parens mostly just add noise.